# Go Gorm Atomic Update to Increment Counter

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have what is essentially a counter that users can increment.

However, I want to avoid the race condition of two users incrementing the counter at once.

Is there a way to atomically increment a counter using Gorm as opposed to fetching the value from the database, incrementing, and finally updating the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the basic ORM features, you can use `FOR UPDATE` as [query option](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Extra-Querying-option) when retrieving the record, the database will lock the record for that specific connection until that connection issues an `UPDATE` query to change that record.

Both the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements *must* happen on the same connection, which means you need to wrap them in a transaction (otherwise Go may send the second query over a different connection).

Please note that this **will make every other connection that wants to `SELECT` the same record wait** until you've done the `UPDATE`. That is not an issue for most applications, but if you either have very high concurrency or the time between `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and the `UPDATE` after that is long, this may not be for you.

In addition to `FOR UPDATE`, the `FOR SHARE` option sounds like it can also work for you, with less locking contentions (but I don't know it well enough to say this for sure).

*Note: This assumes you use an RDBMS that supports `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`; if it doesn't, please update the question to tell us which RDBMS you are using.*

Another option is to just go around the ORM and do `db.Exec("UPDATE counter_table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = ?", 42)` (though see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945125/1073170 for some pitfalls).

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to use GORM transactions (https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html).

```
    err := db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        // Get model if exist
        var feature models.Feature
        if err := tx.Where("id = ?", c.Param("id")).First(&feature).Error; err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Increment Counter
        if err := tx.Model(&feature).Update("Counter", feature.Counter+1).Error; err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        c.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    c.Status(http.StatusOK)
```

Comment: This answer may not correct. As @Jory Geerts syas you shoud use `FOR UPDATE` query options to ensure row mutual exclusion. 

After execute: `tx.Where("id = ?", c.Param("id")).First(&feature).Error`,but before excute: `tx.Model(&feature).Update("Counter", feature.Counter+1).Error`.

`feature.Counter` may changed by another transaction, so update `feature.Counter` to `feature.Counter+1` won't correct.